# Javascript + JQuery Vector Maps

Tags: javascript, jqvmap

Being very (very) new to JavaScript, I am stuck with the following problem when using JQuery VectorMaps:

When I am highlightening  a country with this syntax, everything works perfectly:

```
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'colors', {  'us': '#1caf9a' });
```

However when I put **exactly** `'us'` into a variable, say `country_name` like this :

```
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'colors', {  country_name : '#1caf9a' });
```

it doesn't work -  I don't understand why?
when putting `alert(country_name)` it gives exactly `'us'`.

Also `country_name` cannot be auto-completed in this situation, because of the presence of `:`

Could anyone please help me ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actually found the solution ! I am very silly.

Since it is a key-value pair I have to do the following:

```
var keyval = {}
keyval[country_name] = '#1caf9a'
```

and then

```
jQuery('#vmap').vectorMap('set', 'colors',  keyval);
```